# How do I interrupt writing an assembly using the Mako SDK?

Tags: c++, pdf, xps, mako-sdk

I'm writing an assembly using the Mako SDK. I'm using the `writeAssembly(...)` method of `IPDFOutput`, but I don't know how I can cancel writing the assembly, if it's a large, long running file.

I see that I can provide a `ProgressCallbackFunc`, but I'm not sure how to signal the write to be cancelled.

How I can interrupt the writing the assembly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `writeAssembly(...)` includes a parameter for a progress call back, as you pointed out. From the callback, you can simply throw an error from there to terminate interrupt and end the `writeAssembly(...)` call.

An example of a callback function that terminates when ESC is pressed may look like:

```
static void progressFunc(void *priv, float progress)
{
    wprintf(L"Percentage complete: %3.1f%%\r", progress * 100.0);
    if (_kbhit())
    {
        if (_getch() == 27) // ESC;
          throwEDLError(EDL_ERR_ABORTED);
    }
}
```

The `writeAssembly(...)` call would then look like this:

```
output->writeAssembly(assembly, outputFilePath, progressFunc);
```